# How do I fit cumulative distribution function of normal distribution to data points?

Tags: c#, normal-distribution, data-fitting

I have data which needs to be fitted to the formula

```
y = a*CDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]
```

Where I need to find a,m and s

I have tested the fit with Mathematica, and it finds the fit fairly fast and it fits the data nicely.

However, I need to implement this is c#.

Currently I've implemented a way to estimate params by going down the gradient hill, but my implementation is very slow (around .5s per estimation)

What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implementation by John Cook:  https://www.johndcook.com/blog/csharp_phi/

and I will replicate it below:

```
static double Phi(double x)
{
    // constants
    double a1 = 0.254829592;
    double a2 = -0.284496736;
    double a3 = 1.421413741;
    double a4 = -1.453152027;
    double a5 = 1.061405429;
    double p = 0.3275911;

    // Save the sign of x
    int sign = 1;
    if (x < 0)
        sign = -1;
    x = Math.Abs(x) / Math.Sqrt(2.0);

    // A&S formula 7.1.26
    double t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p*x);
    double y = 1.0 - (((((a5*t + a4)*t) + a3)*t + a2)*t + a1)*t * Math.Exp(-x*x);

    return 0.5 * (1.0 + sign*y);
}

static void TestPhi()
{
    // Select a few input values
    double[] x = 
    {
        -3, 
        -1, 
        0.0, 
        0.5, 
        2.1 
    };

    // Output computed by Mathematica
    // y = Phi[x]
    double[] y = 
    { 
        0.00134989803163, 
        0.158655253931, 
        0.5, 
        0.691462461274, 
        0.982135579437 
    };

    double maxError = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    {
        double error = Math.Abs(y[i] - Phi(x[i]));
        if (error > maxError)
            maxError = error;
    }

        Console.WriteLine("Maximum error: {0}", maxError);
}
```